# Outlook 2013 not showing emails older than aprox. 6months old in any folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

I migrated a VP of our company to Office 365 and now he's not seeing emails in folders that there should be. The problem seems to affect all folders but only emails after about 6-12 months old.

Other "clues" I've found are:

- Emails can be seen from the Office 365 Outlook Web Access interface
- The folders in Outlook will show the proper count of emails [75]
- Outlook is pointed to an exchange server (Office 365)

I suspect it's some sort of "don't sync if older than X" type setting but I have no idea where that setting would be.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I Found the answer

1. File
2. account settings -> account settings
3. From the "account settings" window select the email account
4. Click Change
5. Under Offline settings move the slider to the far right till it reads "all"
6. Click Next
7. Restart outlook

Answer (score -4):

Go into email account setting and set your server from IMAP to POP. You may need help from your service provider. IMAP mirrors the service providers server and some service providers dump your emails after 2 weeks regardless of your setting. Hope this helps.