# View old Mails on Exchange server in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-client

OK - feel a little stupid for asking this. Probably it is just one checkbox to  select, but I can't find it...

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/724096/215109), I want to view mails that are older than six months in MS Outlook 2013. As described there, my Outlook is also configured to download only messages that are older than 6 months.
[image]
However, I would sometimes like to view older messages than that in my inbox. I know Outlook can access older mails than that, e.g. when I use the search function. But in the folder view I can't find a way.

Does anyone know how to do this?

---

**EDIT 1**
Sometimes (but not always) this text is shown below the list of emails:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, well. Finally found it by myself... Click on `Folder`>`View on Server`.

[image]
However it seems there is a bug in Outlook involved. After clicking this button the "*Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange*" (see EDIT 1 above) dialog re-appeared.

**EDIT**: One more thing - MS Office was helplessly outdated, because for whatever reason Windows Update did not update Office. After a successful update the bug was gone too.

Answer (score 1):

In Offline Settings set "mail to keep offline" to all as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-how-much-mail-to-keep-offline-f3a1251c-6dd5-4208-aef9-7c8c9522d633). Restart Outlook and perform a send and receive. Alternatively, you can set your inbox to [automatically archive](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Archive-older-items-manually-FA03020E-55AF-4EEB-94FB-925F640D942D) older items to a .pst file which is saved to your hard drive and accessible within Outlook.

You can also make "View on Server" the default view. You set online view as the default by turning off Cached Exchange Mode. This allows you to view all mail by configuring your inbox to point directly to the Exchange server. The downside is not having access when offline.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft actually does have [KB2898376](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2898376) available which exactly describes the problem. Intuitively, I tried their workaround and it did not work for me. Using the above mentioned 'View on server' icon does work for me.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post an answer to confirm that another answer worked.  The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question, and each answer should contribute another solution.  The way to indicate that an answer was useful is to invest a little time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://superuser.com/help/privileges) to upvote answers you like.

Comment: This answer was excactly what I was looking for and added a lot of value for me !