# Outlook 2016 Not Displaying All Messages

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

A user is using an iPhone and Outlook 2016 on a laptop. Both sync with the same OFfice 365 (Exchange Online) e-mail account.

The iPhone, and Mail Online through portal.office.com, are always synced with the mailbox correctly, showing all e-mails received.

Outlook however, seems to miss every other e-mail- they don't show in the inbox. searching the current mailbox for the missing emails will usually return them in the results. If you restart the PC, it then appears to have updated correctly with the missing emails then present.

We've reinstalled Office, re-added the mail profile, and Microsoft support can't seem to see any issues. The issue also appears present on a different laptop with Office 2016- logged in to test. There are no mailbox rules applied and we reset the views.

Are they any other suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Are all updates for Office installed on the laptop? Take a look at this answer and see if it applies to what you are doing. https://superuser.com/a/724650/97028

Comment: It's not this - it's current messages and the slider is already on 'all'.

Comment: Are all the updates installed?

Comment: Have you checked weather it takes time to download or if you restart only it is downloading.

Comment: Office is fully up to date. Not sure what you're asking, vembutech?

Comment: If you manually run "Send/Receive" or hit F9, does it pull the missing messages?

Comment: It does seem to, yes, but it's really inconvenient for the user to keep having to do this. I'm not sure it works each time, either (I'm testing it myself now).